# How to refresh a div alone inside a component angular 4

Tags: angular

I have a div inside a component which is filled based on the result from Web API(basically a list). I have a submit button which adds an new element in the list through Web API call. Once I click on submit button element gets added in the list in DB, but its not shown in the div. I have to refresh the page every time for the data to be available.

Is there anyway to dynamically refresh the div once i click on submit button.

In my html I have

```
    <div class="col-sm-3 pdl0 pr15" *ngFor="let item of IdList;let i=index;">
        <a class="prevbtn" id="preview_{{i}}" (click)="Open(i)">{{item.Id}}</a>
      </div>
```

In my ts file on ngInit, I am getting the values from Web API call in the list as below:

```
              this.Service.GetRecords(this.EmpNum)
                .catch(this.handleError)
                .subscribe((res) => {
                  this.Service.IdList= res;
                },
                error => {
                  console.log(error)
                });
```

On Click of submit button, a new Id gets added in the db through web api call and gets updated in the list and opens a success popup as below:

```
   let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(Alert, {
                width: '30%',
                data: { alertMessage: "Id" + res.Id+ " has been created" }
              });
```

On click of OK in the popup I want the div which displays the list of Id to be refreshed so that the newly added data will be visible.

Can you please help me in achieving this.

Comment: You have `IdList` property in component, currently you are assigning response to property in service `this.Service.IdList= res;`

Answer (score 0):

As you are getting newly added object in respone from service after save, you can just push new record to `IdList` after successful save, where you are calling success popup, like below:

```
this.IdList.push(res)
```

This should update the component.

Comment: I have tried it, but its not reflecting in the page until and unless i refresh the page. How to refresh the div alone, so that user dont have to refresh the page

Comment: You have `IdList` property in component?

Comment: It looks odd. getting refreshed after the property change is the reason why angular exist. Can you check if you have any changeDetection strategy ON on your component.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same requirement and i use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`. This will refresh your template automatically when the data is updated. You can read about it [here](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/change-detection/change_detection_strategy_onpush.html)